# Problem with vagrant in Windows Linux Subsytem

Tags: vagrant, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having a problem after I installed vagrant on Windows Linux Subsytem.
I know that vagrant is installed because I checked vagrant -v.
Vagrant 2.2.7

But every command I give from vagrant it executes the same error.

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/util/which.rb:37: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/tiedmud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1 in PATH, mode 040777
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:1059:in `chmod': Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /mnt/c/Users/ricar/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key (Errno::EPERM)
        from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:1059:in `chmod'
        from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:1059:in `copy_insecure_private_key'
        from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:166:in `initialize'
        from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/bin/vagrant:154:in `new'
        from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/bin/vagrant:154:in `<main>'
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you upgraded Vagrant from 1.0 to higher version.Please remove old version and reinstall.
RubyGemmethod is gone.
Installing Vagrant
Installing Vagrant is extremely easy. Head over to the Vagrant downloads page and get the appropriate installer or package for your platform. Install the package using standard procedures for your operating system.

The installer will automatically add vagrant to your system path so that it is available in terminals. If it is not found, please try logging out and logging back in to your system (this is particularly necessary sometimes for Windows).

**`Looking for the gem install? Vagrant 1.0.x had the option to be installed as a RubyGem. This installation method is no longer supported. If you have an old version of Vagrant installed via Rubygems, please remove it prior to installing newer versions of Vagrant.**

[Use this  login as root  on safe mode](https://www.maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu/)

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled vagrant and it didnt work.
The problem was the /home/tiedmud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1 I got one by one, until I get this error message:
Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
This I cant remove with chmod. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Go in safe mode with root login  and delete with chmod and root with root.check this https://www.maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu/